# System failure during aptitude upgrade resulted in broken package: No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/filelist.py'

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, 16.04

My system was upgrading when an error ocurried and it rebooted. Once I got into busybox, I had to run `fsck /dev/sda1` and confirm each correction.

So far, so good. When I got Ubuntu back, I tried to get it to continue the update. Then I've got this error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package. Trying to recover:  
Configuring python3.5 (3.5.2-2~16.01) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 122, in compile
    source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/filelist.py'
dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.5 (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5 is not configured yet.
```

`sudo dpkg --reconfigure python3.5` had the same error. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.5` resulted in

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3.5:amd64
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to look for the file `/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/filelist.py` in the Internet. Got to this [list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpython3.5-stdlib/filelist), that says the file is part of `libpython3.5-stdlib`.

### What I did

I downloaded the libpython3.5-stdlib DEB file from [a mirror](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2~16.01_amd64.deb), and then run

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/adam/Downloads/libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2~16.01_amd64.deb
```

### What I would try if it happened again

I would try to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.5-stdlib` or `sudo dpkg --reconfigure libpython3.5-stdlib` before downloading. Not sure it would work, but it is worth the try.

---

I am posting it because these steps proved helpful to me. I used to always solve problems with `dpkg --reconfigure` and/or `apt-get install --reinstall`, but it failed me now. This is a specific scenario but can be made a bit generic. Those are the generic steps I'd suggest:

1. Search the Internet for the file mentioned in the error.
2. If you found a package, try to reinstall this package, instead of the one whose installation is failing.
3. If you could not get it via `dpkg --reconfigure` or `apt-get`, download the package from a mirror and install with `dpkg -i . Pay attention to the version.
4. Eventually, if the installation fails, try to unpack the DEB file and copy the missing file to the correct path.
5. After all, if you got success, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, just to be sure.

It is not guaranteed it would solve your problems, but those are steps that helped me and I did not figured out before.